# changes not reflecting in my site

Tags: php, caching, smarty

see I am trying to do some changes in my php, smarty web site. But changes are not reflecting .

this is the .htaccess code . Is there any errror?

```
# Begin cache control #
ExpiresActive on
<FilesMatch ".*">
Header unset Cache-Control
Header unset Expires
Header unset Last-Modified
FileETag None
Header unset Pragma
</FilesMatch>
# End cache control #
```

Comment: Does a forced refresh (e.g. CMD-R on OS-X) show the updated website?

Comment: refer to this http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html

Answer (score 0):

isn't it .htaccess instead of .hntaccess? Sorry but I stall can't make comments!